# Whats the way to format a date after using get_posts()

Tags: date-time, get-posts

I see that theres no way to get a formatted date from a function like

```
echo get_the_date($post->ID, 'd M Y');
```

`get_the_date` only works with the current `$post`. If I used `get_posts()` how can I format the date. With pure PHP I can do something like ...

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s', $cp->post_date)->format('d M Y');
```

but its abit long, and I don't know if there's a need to actually create a `DateTime` object, perhaps its a waste of resources?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($cp->post_date));` ... or better use the wordpress functionado `echo mysql2date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $cp->post_date);`

Comment: +1 for `mysql2date()`, it's how `get_the_date()` does it internally.

Comment: <?php echo mysql2date( get_option('date_format'), $cp->post_date ); ?> to use the configuration date set in wordpress admin